# Convert a Double to Hex notation in Swift

Tags: swift, hex

How do I convert a very large number into hex?

For example, 647751843213568900000 in hex is 0x231d5cd577654ceab3. I'm able to easily go from hex to double with:

```
let hex: Double = 0x231d5cd577654ceab3
```

However I can't work out how to go from Double back to hex. What am I missing?

The following **does not work** as it overflows when stored as an 'Int':

```
let hexConverted = String(647751843213568900000, radix: 16)
```

Comment: `647751843213568900000` exceeds the range of 64-bit numbers, and also exceeds the 52-bit mantissa in Double, so you *cannot* store it exactly as a floating point number.

Comment: Understood. Do you know how I could go about solving this problem? What should/could it be stored as instead, without losing any accuracy?

Comment: What do you need to do with this value? Perform mathematical operations? Display it? The answer will depend on what you're looking to do.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm using it to encode and decode data. So I don't need to display it, I need it to be the exact conversion for data handling purposes.

Comment: Will you need to perform mathematical operations using this number? I ask because if so, you'll likely need a BigNum-type library. If you're just ferrying this value around for data handling, you might be able to just keep it as a string all the way throughout your app if you don't need to touch it.

Comment: @ItaiFerber correct, keeping it as a string is what I require. However the above is just an example. In the real case I have a rather large Double and I need to turn it into its hex value... (without knowing the hex value to begin with)

Comment: Go for Swift 4, you can define integers of any length there.

Comment: @Sulthan can you be more specific? How would you implement it in Swift4?

Comment: @DavidT Well, technically big integer implementations already exist for Swift 3, for example https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-Big-Integer. In Swift 4 it will be only easier to work with them.

Comment: If number type storage is an issue, you may look into https://github.com/CryptoCoinSwift/UInt256

Answer (score 5):

The basic algorithm (Swift 5) is the following:

```
func representationOf<T: FixedWidthInteger>(_ number: T, base: T) -> String {
    var buffer: [Int] = []
    var n = number
    
    while n > 0 {
        buffer.append(Int(n % base))
        n /= base
    }
    
    return buffer
        .reversed()
        .map { String($0, radix: Int(base)) }
        .joined()
}

print(representationOf(647751843213568900, base: 16))
```

Of course, this is what `String(_:radix:)` is doing so there is no need for us to implement it by ourselves.

Your real problem is not the encoding but the representation of big integers.

There are multiple implementations out there already, for example https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-Big-Integer. Some of them already have functions for hex encoding.

<strike>In Swift 4 it will be possible to declare your own implementation of higher `IntXXX` (conforming to `FixedWidthInteger`) and the problem will become a bit easier:</strike>

```
typealias Int128 = DoubleWidth<Int64>
typealias Int256 = DoubleWidth<Int128>

let longNumber = Int256("231d5cd577654ceab3", radix: 16)!
print(longNumber)
print(String(longNumber, radix: 16))
```

But unfortunately, the `DoubleWidth` is not implemented in Xcode 9 Beta 4 yet.

For some values your can also use the `Decimal` type. Using the algorithm written above:

```
extension Decimal {
    func rounded(mode: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode) -> Decimal {
        var this = self
        var result = Decimal()
        NSDecimalRound(&result, &this, 0, mode)
        
        return result
    }
    
    func integerDivisionBy(_ operand: Decimal) -> Decimal{
        let result = (self / operand)
        return result.rounded(mode: result < 0 ? .up : .down)
    }
    
    func truncatingRemainder(dividingBy operand: Decimal) -> Decimal {
        return self - self.integerDivisionBy(operand) * operand
    }
}

extension Decimal {
    init(_ string: String, base: Int) {
        var decimal: Decimal = 0
        
        let digits = Array(string)
            .map { String($0) }
            .map { Int($0, radix: base)! }
        
        for digit in digits {
            decimal *= Decimal(base)
            decimal += Decimal(digit)
        }
        
        self.init(string: decimal.description)!
    }
}

func representationOf(_ number: Decimal, base: Decimal) -> String {
    var buffer: [Int] = []
    var n = number
    
    while n > 0 {
        buffer.append((n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: base) as NSDecimalNumber).intValue)
        n = n.integerDivisionBy(base)
    }
    
    return buffer
        .reversed()
        .map { String($0, radix: (base as NSDecimalNumber).intValue ) }
        .joined()
}

let number = Decimal("231d5cd577654ceab3", base: 16)
print(number) // 647751843213568961203
print(representationOf(number, base: 16)) // 231d5cd577654ceab3
```

Note how your value got truncated when converted to `Double`.

Comment: Thanks for the potential answer @Sulthan. Unfortunately it has the same problem as my initial question, i.e. the error is that the integer overflows. The integer I'm using is the same one in the question: 647751843213568900000.

Comment: @DavidT That's why I am telling you that your real problem is the representation of integers and that you should use a library to do that.

Comment: understood. I prefer not to use external libraries though. I'm hoping someone can come up with an answer...

Comment: @DavidT As you can see, the implementation is pretty simple. Start by representing the value somehow, then implement division on that and then you can use the algorithm above.

Comment: @DavidT I have added an example using the `Decimal` type. Suprisingly, the result is not `0x231d5cd577654ceab3` but it seems to be correct.

Comment: (and that's because you lose precision when converting the value to `Double`).

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution :

```
func toHex(number : Double) -> String
{
    var n = number;
    var reminders : [Double] = [];
    while true
    {
        let reminder = n % 16;
        n = floor(n/16.0);

        reminders.append(reminder);

        if(n == 0.0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    var hex = "";        
    var i = reminders.count-1;
    while(i > -1)
    {
        hex = hex + hexChar(reminders[i]);
        i = i-1;
    }

    return hex;
}


func hexChar(n : Double) -> String
{
    switch n
    {
    case 15: return "F";
    case 14: return "E";
    case 13: return "D";
    case 12: return "C";
    case 11: return "B";
    case 10: return "A";
    default: return String(Int(n))
    }
}
```

---

```
toHex(647751843213568900000.0); //231D5CD577654C0000
```

Comment: The result is incorrect though. `Double` does not have the required precision.

Comment: yes i notice that now , i think there is problem with `%` operator , i will try to solve the issue

Comment: The `Double` type cannot represent the value exactly, it just won't work.

Comment: sorry , but what do you mean by **"Double type cannot represent the value exactly"** ?

Comment: `Double` type can represent only about 15-17 decimal digits. The value `647751843213568900000` has 21 digits. You can see that in the OP. Assigning `0x231d5cd577654ceab3` to `Double` ends up being `647751843213568900000` which is not correct. The last few digits got truncated to zeros. Your mathematical operations are not correct because every value too big to be represented in a `Double` gets truncated. That's why I have used the `Decimal` type which can achieve about 35 decimal digits of precision.