# Convert NSDecimalNumber to hex String

Tags: ios, swift, hex, nsdecimalnumber

I managed to convert a NSDecimalNumber to a hex String using BInt library. Here is my code:

```
public func toDecimalHex(value: NSDecimalNumber) -> String{
    let bint = BInt(value.stringValue)
    return (bint?.asString(radix: 16))!
}
```

example:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: "1000000000000000000000000")
let hex = toDecimalHex(value: number)

//result : d3c21bcecceda1000000
```

Basically, how can I convert without using any library like BInt? This brings too much overhead. I just want to get rid of it.

Comment: Do you know the algorithm for converting string representation of numbers from one base to another?

Comment: Yes, I know. I tried smth, but it did not work.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184500/669586 there is a sample implementation for `Decimal` (which you should use in Swift instead of `NSDecimalNumber`).

Comment: So, I should change the NSDecimalNumber to Decimal? Right now, it may not be easy for me. Maybe I should try to implement this with NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: They are convertible automatically, e.g. `number as Decimal` would work, too. But yes, you should not use `NSNumber` or `NSDecimalNumber` in Swift (or anything else starting with `NS` with some exceptions, e.g. `NSObject` and `NSAttributedString`).

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks Sulthan.